# In Rails, is the RESTful standard that a GET to /users is for index action, and a POST to /users is for create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking into a Rails plugin, and it seems that to create a user, the HTML form says

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
```

and if I do a

```
rake routes
```

it says:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)           {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
      POST   /users(.:format)           {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
```

so looks like a standard is that a GET to `/controller_name` is to perform the `index` action, while a POST is to perform the `create` action?  Is this almost the 100% standard?  Is there any exception?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default when using Rails' resourceful routes. You can of course override this default in many ways, as described in this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), but you should only do so with good reason.

Comment: is it just a shorthand convention?  Is it equally practical to POST  to `/users/create` to create a user instead of a POST to `/users`? (if POSTing to `/users/create` becomes the convention)

Comment: You can certainly POST to /user/create to create a user, but that isn't RESTful.  Rails promotes a REST approach, but doesn't require it.

Answer (score 1):

Ther answer is **NO**

Rails routs are as flexible as you can imagine.

**BUT**. Rails loves REST style. You can read some wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

REST like CRUD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

So. We have got convention about resources. We can:

- READ list of resources: `GET /resources`
- READ resource: `GET /resources/:id`
- CREATE new resource: `POST /resources`
- UPDATE resource: `PUT /resources/:id`
- DELETE resource: `DELETE /resources/:id`
- READ resource for edit: `GET /resources/:id/edit`
- READ for creating: `GET /resources/new`

This is a basis of REST.